# Java program which sums numbers from 1 to 100

Tags: java

I have been recently started learning Java and would want to make code that sums the numbers from 1 to 100 (result would be 5050)

The code should go like 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10... etc

I have tested it with this code:

```
public class T35{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nmb;
        
        for(nmb= 1; nmb<= 100; nmb++){
          
            System.out.println(nmb);
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

But the result is that it goes from 1 to 100 without adding the numbers.

Not sure if it need to be made with `while` but could not figure the math for it.

Comment: where do you think, you are adding the numbers?

Comment: Like i said, i am new in Java and have just started learning, i have tested `nmb = nmb + nmb` but did not worked.

Comment: You managed to create a loop that  `print` into the console. Now, use  a variable `sum` in that loop a print it outside of the loop. You should use a sheet of paper first ot no what your code should look like ...

Comment: I would better feel solving your basic understanding than answering this question. When you say `nmb = nmb + nmb`, you have lost the track of loop . This will be true in any language, nothing to do with java.

Comment: @JaskaJokela that would mean you're multiplying nmb x 2 every iteration, of course it wouldn't work. This is not a problem with java, it's more like you're having trouble with thinking about the problem. It's something that happens to all of us when we start, we can't seem to be able to solve such basic problems. Don't worry, in a few years you won't be able to think like a human anymore, and you'll try to find an algorithm for everything. Welcome to the journey.

Comment: For understanding purpose, "_Not sure if it need to be made with while _", any loop works the same, you have a block of statement that will be executed based on a condition (some are execute at least one, some could never be executed), but the choice of the loop is not important here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nmb++` is equal to `nmb = nmb + 1`. It only adds one till it's 101, which is when it stops.

You should add a new variable, let's call it `total`, and sum `nmb` to it every iteration.

```
public class T35{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nmb;
        int total = 0;

        for(nmb= 1; nmb<= 100; nmb++){
            total = total + nmb;
        }
        System.out.println(total);

    }

}
```

This will do what you want.

Comment: What's important is if you've understood where your mistake was. Did you understand?

Comment: Yea i think i understood now, i did not had the math where i would have added all the numbers between 1 - 100. But learning is the best way to learn more.

Answer (score 5):

Hey you can find the sum from 1 to 100 like this also. Just a option.

You can use the mathematical formula for sum of numbers i.e n(n+1)/2

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i =100;
        int sum = (i)*(i+1)/2;
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Shinratensei How do you know that he is asking question about while loop?? Is it written anywhere in the question? And I have written that it is just a option to calculate the sum of the number. I don't think you have got the question dear......

Comment: Good logic bro.. good Programming always depends on good logic.

Comment: @ Shinra tensei  see the solutions above dear, I think that his doubt about for loops has been cleared so thats why I have given him alternative, i.e you can also think like this. This is also a way to find the sum of numbers if you do not want to use the loops...

Comment: Yeah you are correct dear...., but it doesn't make sense to post the same solution that has already been posted....

Answer (score 2):

You have started to learn Java by implementing a `for` loop. Unfortunately that is probably the least intuitive syntax in the entire language. It was inherited from `c` and, while convenient, really makes no sense: the meaning of the three positions bears no resemblance to natural language (unlike `if`, `while`, `implements` etc.). Much better to start with simpler constructs until you get the hang of things.

Java 8 provides a more intuitive (in my opinion) way of representing a group of numbers to add. In your case you don't really want to iterate through all the numbers from 1 to 100. You just want a way to represent all those numbers and then sum them. In Java 8 this concept is represented by a stream of integers: the `IntStream` class. It provides a handy way of asking for 'all integers between x and y': the `rangeClosed` method. And it provides a method for adding all the integers together: the `sum` method.

So your operation could be implemented with a single, simple Java statement:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).sum();
```

That seems a pretty straightforward statement to read: give me a stream of integers in the range from 1 to 100 and then sum them. Even better you don't need to declare a variable you have no real use for.

Answer (score 1):

You output the value of `nmb` that is the numeric value that you iterate on, you don't increment the actual value with the current sum.

You should introduce a local variable before the loop to compute and maintain the actual sum. 
Besides,  `int nmb;` could be declared directly in the loop.
Narrowing the scope of variables makes the code more robust.

```
public class T35{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i= 1; i<= 100; i++){    
            sum += i;
            System.out.println(sum);    
        }    
    }

}
```

Comment: you forgot to declare the type of `i`

Comment: @Shinra tensei Thank you for the typo !

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It will print the value like

1+2+3.. + 100 = 5050

```
public class T35{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int total=0;

    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();

    for(int nmb= 1; nmb<= 100; nmb++){

        total+=nmb;
        stringBuilder.append(nmb);
        if(nmb!=100)
        stringBuilder.append("+");

    }
    stringBuilder.append(" = "+total);
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class sum1TO100 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(1,100).sum());
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SumsUpPractice2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        int count, sum;
        sum = 0;
        for (count = 1;count <= 100; count++) {
            sum = sum + count;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

We initialize `sum` with 0 and add `count` to it at each iteration.

Comment: Hi @Lin77, welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68781007/edit) your answer, put your code in answer. Screenshots aren't useful for copy-pasting :)

Comment: It's better now. Can you add some explanations why your answer is better than [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46193930) one? Answers without explanations (code only) are not considered as good ones.

Comment: @Vadik Oops it seems my answer is same as the accepted one. Sorry I didn't notice that.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ClassExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;
            for(int number = 2;number<=100;number++){
                total = total +number;
                System.out.println(total);
            }
    }
```

}